# Woo commerce Error: How to enable soap client on debian server?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, woocommerce, soap, debian

I have deployed WordPress on debian VM on GCP.
I am getting an error:

> Your server does not have the SoapClient class enabled - some gateway plugins which use SOAP may not work as expected.

I have run below commands to install soap client:

```
sudo apt-get install php-soap
```

After installation, it is still same showing same error.

When I checked the php version, it shows below warning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'soap' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/soap (/usr/lib/php/20190902/soap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/soap.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/soap
.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

What to do to remove this error?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes, I restart Apache. It is still showing same error.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be that the `php7.3-soap` package is corrupted, please try reinstalling it and after that restart the Apache service, then validate the error is no longer present.

```
$ sudo apt-get reinstall php7.3-soap
$ php -m | grep soap
$ php -v
```

Please note that Debian 10 (buster) default Php version is 7.3.